# Using MVC in Javascript without any server-side language?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I'm in the process of trying to wrap my head around using MVC and using it with javascript. I'll be making a mobile app with HTML5 and don't plan to use any server side languages only local storage.

How can this be achieved? 
I'm usually thrown off by the model since it relies on the back end language from my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Model doesn't rely on the back end. MVC in conceptually simple:

1. **Controller** gets request.
2. **Controller** calls for **Model** to do all of the logic (be it database interaction, localStorage interaction of whatever)
3. **Model** returns data to **Controller**.
4. **Controller** calls **View** accordingly, and if needed, passes data from the **Model**.

This means, that Model doesn't have to use a server side language, it's a placeholder for the application logic.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple `MV*` frameworks available. You don't have to have server support to use them.

- [BackboneJS](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)
- [EmberJS](http://emberjs.com/)
- [javascriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/)

There are many more, but these three come to mind first. Enjoy

Comment: There is a great blog post by Gordon L. Hempton, where he reviews the 10 "biggest" Javascript MVC frameworks [check it out](http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/)

Comment: Im new to the whole MVC concept, which would be the better choice for a novice?

Comment: I personally have used backboneJS and i can vouch for that. Whats awesome about backbone is that the community support for that is just awesome. It's really easy to find help. I'd say go with that.

Comment: I think backbone is overkill after looking it in comparison to ember. I think I may try to wrap my head around ember to get the concept before trying backbone.

Answer (score 0):

MVC development has nothing to do with server side scripting.

It only relate to the type of architecture you are taking to develop your application.

It only means you have Models, Views and Controllers. Models can be object generated from javascript which are used with the Views in order to render some data.

Controllers are there to hold the logic and behaviour between the view and the models.

Well that's a very basic overview, but by no means does MVC means backend services or ajax calls.

This article might help http://www.alexatnet.com/articles/model-view-controller-mvc-javascript